# Is there a way to specify which theme to use for certain UI elements?

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, themes

For example, using the Light Theme means that the back and appbar buttons are black.
However when using a darker app bar colour, the contrast of the buttons is stark.
Here's a screen grab, ignore the quality of the white one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr0Zs.png

Is there any way to directly access the styles that result in one theme's icons vs anothers?

Note: I'm building a C# + XAML app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start the button will be looking somewhat like this:

[image: start]

Under the StandartStyles.xml you have to look for the style `AppBarButtonStyle` first to change your icon color find `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>`

Now you replace `{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}` with the color you want you can use both `white` and `#FFFFFFFF`. now you have changed the visuals of your icon and you should have something like this

[image]

Now you need to style the text below this is done by finding the `</TextBlock` tag a few lines down and also changeing the forground property there

[image: step two]

Now you have a nice looking icon but as soon as you mouse over it all turns quiet ugly agien. in order to change the diffrent states move down to the `<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">` tag here you will find a tag `<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">` as you might suspect this changes the properties of button when you hover the mouse over it.

```
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
    <!-- the background of the actionbar-> !--><DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="yourBackgroundColor"/> 
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
    <!-- the icon of the actionbar-> --><DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="yourActionBarIconColor"/> 
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

If you keep scrolling down you will find `<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the CSS that each theme uses by expanding the References node under the project in Visual Studio, then expanding the `Windows Library for JavasScript 1.0` node and then the `css` folder.

The relevant lines for the colors of the AppBar seem to start on line 2621 of my `ui-dark.css` file. Also line 2448 specifies the color of for a `.win-commandimage` item, which is the icons for most appbar commands are. You should be able to override these settings in your project's stylesheet.

Comment: My bad, didn't specify this is a C# + XAML app

Comment: The problem isn't with choosing an AppBarColour, it's that by choosing the light theme, the icons that appear in app are black. If I choose the dark theme, the icons are white. I want the white icons with a light theme, which is the problem (and my question).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Windows 8 just uses the Foreground colour (which it inherits from the selected theme style).

Which means that all you need do, is set the foreground to change the icon colour, winner!

Answer (score 0):

The colours of the App Bar buttons for each theme are defined as resources which you can override. I've described the process at [Windows 8 – Overriding Metro app resources](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/07/technical/windows-8-overriding-metro-app-resources/).

For your approach is should be simple enough to grab the Light App Bar button resources and use them to override the Dark resources.

Comment: I've read that article before, it doesn't mention the AppBarButtons, which was the problem I was having. If you can find the correct key to override to target just the AppBarbuttons (rather than the Foreground colour as I mention in my answer), I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: The resources you need to override are the ones that start with "AppBarItem". You'll need to grab the light versions of those resources from "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design\themeresources.xaml" as mentioned my article and include them in your app.